# Find out why Apache stops running every Sunday morning

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, ubuntu-16.04

I have Apache set up on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.

For some reason, at about the same time every Sunday morning, Apache stops running.

When it stops, I then run `systemctl status apache2` and see:

```
Mar 04 06:25:24 xxxxxx apache2[11178]:  * Stopping Apache httpd web server apache2
```

So somehow Apache was stopped. When it is stopped, there is nothing in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. When I start Apache again I see:

```
[Sun Mar 04 09:44:10.875444 2018] [core:warn] [pid 22442:tid 140355746498432] AH00098: pid file /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
```

From `/var/log/syslog` it seems that Apache was reloaded (also ProFTPD) and then was stopped at `06:25:24`:

```
Mar  4 06:25:11 xxxxxx systemd[1]: Reloading LSB: Apache2 web server.
Mar  4 06:25:11 xxxxxx apache2[11014]:  * Reloading Apache httpd web server apache2
Mar  4 06:25:11 xxxxxx apache2[11014]:  *
Mar  4 06:25:11 xxxxxx systemd[1]: Reloaded LSB: Apache2 web server.
Mar  4 06:25:18 xxxxxx systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Starts ProFTPD daemon...
Mar  4 06:25:18 xxxxxx proftpd[11083]:  * Stopping ftp server proftpd
Mar  4 06:25:18 xxxxxx proftpd[11083]:    ...done.
Mar  4 06:25:18 xxxxxx systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Starts ProFTPD daemon.
Mar  4 06:25:18 xxxxxx systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts ProFTPD daemon...
Mar  4 06:25:18 xxxxxx proftpd[11094]:  * Starting ftp server proftpd
Mar  4 06:25:18 xxxxxx proftpd[11094]: 2018-03-04 06:25:18,666 xxxxxx proftpd[11104]: mod_dso/0.5: module 'mod_tls.c' already loaded
Mar  4 06:25:18 xxxxxx proftpd[11094]: 2018-03-04 06:25:18,667 xxxxxx proftpd[11104]: mod_dso/0.5: module 'mod_sftp.c' already loaded
Mar  4 06:25:19 xxxxxx proftpd[11094]:    ...done.
Mar  4 06:25:19 xxxxxx systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts ProFTPD daemon.
Mar  4 06:25:24 xxxxxx apache2[11178]:  * Stopping Apache httpd web server apache2
Mar  4 06:25:24 xxxxxx apache2[11178]:  *
```

How do I find out why Apache stops, or what process is stopping Apache (for what reason) so I can prevent it from happening again?

Comment: Anything running on Sunday morning (Crontab? DB tables cleanup?)? How much free memory have you got usually?

Comment: Usually about 4GB memory free. There are no cron jobs configured specifically for Sundays.

Comment: something odd in /var/log/syslog ?

Comment: I'm editing the question by adding `/var/log/syslog` entries...

Comment: In the meantime, maybe write a script to check that it's running and if not to send you an email and then start the service. Run something such as [`for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do crontab -u $user -l; done`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134906/how-do-i-list-all-cron-jobs-for-all-users) and see what you see there. Also look into [`systemctl list-timers --all`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329996/is-there-a-way-to-know-when-a-systemd-timer-will-run-next/330018)

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I have already checked all crontabs, nothing there that should stop Apache. Also no timers found that are running on Sundays.

Comment: A couple quick thoughts.... See if you can enable Apache verbose logging and automate turning that on at 12 midnight or something on Sunday unless you can leave it on in the meantime to see if it gives more clue to the issue. Also, consider automating a job that will stop and restart the Apache service at 6:30 AM daily if you can to just refresh the service daily in case it's a memory issue. I read something about extra httpd processes causing issues but not 100% certain if that's related or not but perhaps a night refresh would help if it's a memory related crash... quick thoughts only.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by `logrotate`, which stops Apache when rotating logs.

The problem was solved by editing `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2`, changing `reload` to `graceful`.

Original:

```
postrotate
            if /etc/init.d/apache2 status > /dev/null ; then \
                /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null; \
            fi;
endscript
```

Edited:

```
postrotate
            if /etc/init.d/apache2 status > /dev/null ; then \
                /etc/init.d/apache2 graceful > /dev/null; \
            fi;
endscript
```